# COM object as service or simple executable

Tags: visual-studio-2010, visual-c++, com, navision

I need to create COM object that will be use by Navision in general. I don't want to make dll since I expect better stability and following architecture looks nice for me.

First of all I was confused by selecting executable/service_executable:

[image]

When is better to use one and when another?

Then I need to add ATL object. In service case I have:

[image]

What is `Custom Interface`? Is it ok for `Navision`? Usually I choose `Dual`. I suppose I need to check `"Automation compatible"`

I have following menu when selecting simple executable:

[image]

Comment: "Custom interface" here means "not derived from `IDispatch`". "Automation compatible" means "method parameters still limited to types that would be valid for an `IDispatch`-based interface": some, but not all, automation clients can still consume such interfaces. What kind of interface Navision needs, I have no idea.

Answer (score 0):

- **Executable(EXE):** you need to open a Windows session in order to launch it
- **Service(EXE):** service is launched at startup of host (no need to open a Windows session)
- **Dual**: inherit from `IDispath` interface (COM instance can be called with late binding) + `vtbl` binding. That's why it is called Dual.
- **Custom**: user defined interface that uses `vtbl` binding.(To be called, a proxy/stub has to be provided to the client)
- **Automation interface**: inherit from `IDispath` interface (COM instance can be called with late binding (dynamic invocation))